# PHP Checking if session is registered

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I am creating a simple login script, I have set everything up but I am having trouble with sessions.

At the end of the login check page I have the following code:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1){
    $_SESSION["username"] = 'username';
    $_SESSION["password"] = 'password';
    header("location:success.php");
}else{
    echo "Wrong username or password";
}
```

And on the success.php page I have the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header ("Location: wrong.php");
}
?>

<html>
    <body>
        Login Successful
    </body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when a correct user and pass is entered it takes you to wrong.php, whereas it needs to redirect to wrong.php when someone visits success.php without logging in.

I am quite new to sessions and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to have `session_start()` on every document that uses sessions.. so on your login check page you need to have `session_start()` at the top of the document

Comment: Awesome, i'll post it as an answer if you'd be kind enough to accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make sure `session_start()` is present at the top of any document that requires using sessions..

So at the top of your login check page you need to include `session_start();`